# Python How to join a password protected IRC channel

Tags: python, irc, channel

What is the correct syntaxe to join a password protected IRC channel in python ?

The usual one would be :

```
socket.send("JOIN " +channel+ "\r\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

From RFC 1459:

```
Command: JOIN
Parameters: <channel>{,<channel>} [<key>{,<key>}]
```

Furthermore, you must terminate your lines with CR-LF:

```
IRC messages are always lines of characters terminated with a CR-LF
(Carriage Return - Line Feed) pair, and these messages shall not
exceed 512 characters in length, counting all characters including
the trailing CR-LF.
```

So it's `"JOIN " + channel + " " + key + "\r\n"`

**References:**

- [RFC 1459](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1459.txt)

Comment: Thanks, I should read the RFC more.
I forgot the CR when typing my message, my bad.